# Free and easy file sharing or at least send files within local wifi

Tags: linux, windows, file-sharing, local, wifi-transfer

is there any easy way to share or at least send files within local network (in my case wifi) and between various machines with Kubuntu linux and Windows 7?

I often have to send some files to a computer which is also connected to our home wifi network but need to avoid internet due slow connection.

I am looking for something simple - already tried [LAN Messenger](http://lanmsngr.sourceforge.net/) - the file sending works nice in Windows but I was not able to make it work in linux.

Currently looking on [Lanshark](http://lanshark.29a.ch/) but also heard about Samba sharing. Am I right that using smb means that everything I put in the sharing folder is automatically available for other users?

Is there any simple solution for this?

thanks

Comment: I would suggest Samba. It is not by default shared with everyone. You can make this the case by changing permissions. This can also be managed from your Linux machine and require username and password authentication.

Comment: Thanks I will check it. I also found Nitroshare: https://quickmediasolutions.com/apps/14/nitroshare which also looks promising.

Comment: Can't say I have used this before. The system you use will depend largely on which OS you use to host/manage the system. Samba of Linux and Nitroshare for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Samba](https://www.samba.org/), [rsync](http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html) or [Bittorrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync) which is also encrypted and simple to use. If you want something a bit more sophisticated, like dropbox, you can deploy an [Owncloud](http://www.owncloud.org) instance.

All of them can work in local network.

Samba in Linux will behave as the "Network Sharing" with Windows, OSX and Linux clients.
There are plenty of options, choose what fits better for you.

Comment: OwnCloud might be a bit overkill, but +1 for the mention.

Comment: I would use Bittorrent Sync. It's simple, fast and secure. And i feel it's more easy to setup than Samba shares.